# Regex - match words that follow the rule "i before e except after c"

Tags: regex

Hi I'm wondering how to match words that follow the spelling rule “i before e
except after c” (such as **brief**, **receipt**, **receive**, **pier**). But **shouldn't** match words that don't follow that rule such as **science**.

What I have here is incorrect (as science shouldn't match) but it's what I got so far:

[image: current progress]
[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/dCQLEj/1)

I don't really know how to do this without using look behind (which I know isn't very well supported).

Comment: can you post a link to your regex101 demo?

Comment: can you articulate, though, in what way "science" is different from "brief", because from a regex engine perspective they are not different.  A regex cannot discern context.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dCQLEj/1

Comment: Try [`\b(?!\w*cie)[a-z]*(?:cei|ie)[a-z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/fJ8eUJ/2)

Comment: why receipt and receive s matched ? they are not i before e

Comment: @sweaver2112 science has a 'c' before the 'ie' whereas brief doesn't. So the rule states that everything matches 'ie' except in the case where it's preceded by a 'c' (in which case it's cei that should match).

Comment: @sweaver2121 the difference between science and brief is that the character "c" precedes the "ie" characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\b\w*(cei|\bie|(?!c)\w(?=ie))\w*\b
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MOtysr/3)

[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 4):

This seems simple enough:

```
[A-Za-z]*(cei|[^c]ie)[A-Za-z]*
```

Comment: Not if the "ie" occurs at beginning of string - you'd need `(^|[^c])` to catch that corner-case.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't know of any such words, do you? The spelling rule is unclear about that anyway, so seems an unnecessary complication to include.

Comment: @Toby `(?<!c)` is neater. It matches both `^` and `[^c]`

Comment: @Bohemian - yes, in regexp syntaxes that have it.  The question specifically mentions the unportability of lookbehind as an issue.

Comment: @toby actually, I'm with Blue on this. There *are* no words in the English language that start with "ie". If [the official Scrabble word list can't find any words starting with "ie"](http://www.wordfind.com/starts-with/IE/), and given the range of oddball strings of characters they consider *are* words, I'm satisfied no such words exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/\b(?![a-z]*cie)[a-z]*(?:cei|ie)[a-z]*/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ8eUJ/3)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?![a-z]*cie)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the word has `cie` after 0+ letters
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ letters
- `(?:cei|ie)` - `cei` or `ie`
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ letters.

Answer (score 0):

I was analysing the text of a novel, looking for the most common words that obeyed and broke the i before e rule. It would appear you're more likely to use a word that breaks rather than one which obeys the rule.

```
import operator, re

ie  = {}
cei = {}
ei  = {}

file = open('1342.txt', 'r')

for line in file:

        line = line.lower()

        # ditch anything that's not a word or a white-space character
        line = re.sub(r'[^\_\w\s]','', line)

        # split line into words
        line = line.split()

        for word in range(len(line)):

                # add the word to the appropriate dictionary or increment 
                # frequency of occurrence if already in that dictionary

                if re.search(r'ie', line[word], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                        if line[word] in ie:
                                ie[line[word]] = ie[line[word]] + 1
                        else:
                                ie[line[word]] = 1

                if re.search(r'cei', line[word], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                        if line[word] in cei:
                                cei[line[word]] = cei[line[word]] + 1
                        else:
                                cei[line[word]] = 1

                if re.search(r'[a-b,d-z]+ei', line[word], flags=re.IGNORECASE):
                        if line[word] in ei:
                                ei[line[word]] = ei[line[word]] + 1
                        else:
                                ei[line[word]] = 1

# sort each dictionary and display the 10 most common words from each

x = sorted(ie.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for word in range(len(x) - 1, len(x) - 10, -1):
    print(x[word])

print()

x = sorted(cei.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for word in range(len(x) - 1, len(x) - 10, -1):
    print(x[word])

print()

x = sorted(ei.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for word in range(len(x) - 1, len(x) - 10, -1):
    print(x[word])
```